# How to have the Sharpe Ratio in vectorBt backtest result?

Tags: python, vectorbt

I am backtesting using vectorBT, a python backtest library, to get the backtest result with Sharpe Ratio.

Here is the sample code

```
import vectorbt as vbt
import yfinance as yf

symbol = 'AAPL'
ohlcv = yf.download(symbol, start='2022-01-01', end='2023-01-01')

entries = ohlcv['Close'] > ohlcv['Close'].rolling(50).mean()
exits = ohlcv['Close'] < ohlcv['Close'].rolling(50).mean()

pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(
    close=ohlcv['Close'],
    entries=entries,
    exits=exits,
    init_cash=10000
)

stats = pf.stats()

print(stats)
```

Here is the result

- Start 2022-01-03 00:00:00
- End 2022-12-30 00:00:00 Period 251
- Start Value 10000.0
- End Value 7982.422082
- Total Return [%] -20.175779
- Benchmark Return [%] -28.613814
- Max Gross Exposure [%] 100.0
- Total Fees Paid 0.0
- Max Drawdown [%] 25.578501
- Max Drawdown Duration 94.0
- Total Trades 9
- Total Closed Trades 9
- Total Open Trades 0
- Open Trade  PnL 0.0
- Win Rate [%] 11.111111
- Best Trade [%] 6.46395
- Worst Trade [%] -5.867954
- Avg Winning Trade [%] 6.46395
- Avg Losing Trade [%] -3.524771
- Avg Winning Trade Duration 41.0
- Avg Losing Trade Duration 4.25
- Profit Factor 0.223676
- Expectancy -224.175324
- Name: Close, dtype: object

How do I have the Sharpe ratio included in the result?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
freq="1d" is a necessary parameter to get the shape ratio etc.,.